# React does not re-render updated map, even with different keys

Tags: reactjs

May be it's a stupid issue, but I can't seem to see it.

I have a file input which uploads an image, and I receive from API multiple images resized into different dimensions.

Before the images are loaded, I don't have a 'file' property in the image object.
After they are loaded - I have the file property.

The problem is, when the resized images are loaded, the map still renders 'no-component'. Even when the key is changed...

Here is the code with some console debugging for more clarity:

```
{newsImages.map(image => {
    console.log('Has file?', image.hasOwnProperty('file'))
    const imageComponent = image.hasOwnProperty('file')
        ? 'has component' // (<AuthorizedImage fileId={image.file} />)
        : 'no component';
    console.log('Image component: ', imageComponent);
    const key = image.label + (image.hasOwnProperty('file') ? image.file : '-');
    console.log('Key: ', key);
    return (
        <div key={key}>
            <FormUploadFile
                label={`Image for ${image.label}`}
                placeholder={"Choose image"}
                onChange={value => console.log(value)}
            />
            {imageComponent}
            <br />
            {key}
        </div>
    )
})}
```

[image: console log]

So far so good. But the web page itself does not show the changes like you can see below:

[image: rendered content]

EDIT: More details on the component. Here is how the images are processed:

```
const [newsImages, setNewsImages] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    Api.NewsImageSizes.List()
        .then(response => {
            let newsImages = [];
            response['hydra:member'].forEach(size => {
                newsImages.push({label: size.label})
            })
            setNewsImages(newsImages.reverse());
        })
        .catch(ErrorHandling.GlobalStateError);
}, []);
```

Then when a file is uploaded...

```
const generateNewsImages = (file) => {
    Api.Files.Upload(file)
        .then(response => {
            Api.News.GenerateImages(response.id)
                .then(response => {
                    response.images.forEach(image => {
                        newsImages.forEach((element, index) => {
                            if (element.label === image.label) {
                                element.file = image.file;
                                newsImages[index] = element;
                            }
                        })
                    })
                    console.log('Setting news images...', newsImages);
                    setNewsImages(newsImages);
                })
                .catch(ErrorHandling.GlobalStateError);
        })
        .catch(ErrorHandling.GlobalStateError);
}
```

And the console again:

[image]

Comment: How is the `newsImages` array updated? Is this part of React state? Can you share a more complete and comprehensive component code example?

Comment: Yes, it's in `useState()` hook, updated with `setNewsImages`.

Comment: Please show us. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are mutating the state in the `generateNewsImages` function.

```
.then(response => {
  response.images.forEach(image => {
    newsImages.forEach((element, index) => { // <-- newsImages is state reference
      if (element.label === image.label) {
        element.file = image.file;   // <-- mutation!!
        newsImages[index] = element;
      }
    })
  })
  console.log('Setting news images...', newsImages);
  setNewsImages(newsImages); // <-- save same reference back into state
})
```

When updating React state you must create shallow copies of all state (*and nested state*) that you are updating.

```
.then(response => {
  const nextNewsImages = newsImages.slice(); // <-- shallow copy state
  response.images.forEach(image => {
    nextNewsImages.forEach((element, index) => {
      if (element.label === image.label) {
        nextNewsImages[index] = {   // <-- new object reference
          ...nextNewsImages[index], // <-- shallow copy
          file: image.file,         // <-- update property
        };
      }
    })
  })
  console.log('Setting news images...', nextNewsImages);
  setNewsImages(nextNewsImages); // <-- save new 
})
```

Comment: Damn you're right... Thanks a lot for catching that little nasty one.

Comment: I still wonder tho - everything is executing correctly, even inside the .map - the console.log() is printing everything. Keys are changed. Everything.
The console.log just before the render is showing the correct UPDATED state, even if I used the same state reference...

Why the problems comes way down - inside the map?

Comment: @vuryss Because you are mutating the array and elements you are able to immediately see the mutations. The "not-rerendering" bit is because React uses shallow reference equality checks as part of it's reconciliation process. Because the `newsImages` array reference never changed, React is likely bailing on rerendering since it *thinks* (*or assumes*) that since the reference didn't change, the data didn't change.

Comment: I see, so even if the keys are different it still decides not to rerender on the same reference because it assumes no changes without even checking the returned jsx. Thanks again :) Hope I don't make this mistake in the future.