# React preserving state even though key has changed

Tags: reactjs

The react component is preserving the "wasEdited" state even when the properties and key are changed.  When any div element is edited from its initial value, the classname of the div row will be changed, thus showing a red border on the left side.

I was able to get around the issue by resetting the state manually every time the "globalId" property is changed.  As you can see in the comment, I suspect this may be a similar issue to this:

[React does not re-render updated map, even with different keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68949376///react-does-not-re-render-updated-map-even-with-different-keys)

But in my case I'm not mutating an object.

```
function Attribute ({globalId, name, value}) {
    const [wasEdited, setWasEdited] = useState(false);

    const handleInput = (e) => {
        e.target.innerHTML === value ? setWasEdited(false) : setWasEdited(true);
    };

    // TODO: This useEffect is a hack to reset the wasEdited state when the globalId changes. I don't understand
    // why this is necessary, since each Attribute component is rendered with a unique key. I think it
    // has something to do with this post on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68949376///react-does-not-re-render-updated-map-even-with-different-keys).
 

    // useEffect(() => {
    //     return () => setWasEdited(false);
    // }, [globalId])

    console.log(`${globalId}-${name}`, wasEdited)

    return (
        <div key={`${globalId}-${name}`} className={wasEdited ? 'row was-edited' : 'row'}>
            <div className='col'>{name}</div>
            <div className='col' onInput={handleInput} contentEditable>{value}</div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is what it looks like:
[image: This is what it looks like]

Comment: I'm confused why you're using `key` here at all as this component isn't rendering any kind of list.  Read the part of the documentation which says "incorrect key usage" https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#extracting-components-with-keys, ensure you are not actually doing the thing the documentation says not to do, and then post the code where you are using `Attribute`.

Comment: The fact that the key changes is a bug in itself. The whole point of the key props is so react internally can keep track of each element. Also, the code shown doesn't need a `key` since you are not rendering a list of elements. If you are rendering a list of `Attribute` components higher in the tree, that's where the `key` props should be set, and it should be done so with a unique id that is persistent between renders.

Comment: @possum - as far as I'm aware, using the key isn't limited to just lists.  It's a way of controlling components : https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state

Comment: @super Thanks! I can't believe I missed that!

Comment: @VukasPajic  It can be, but you're still probably doing the thing the documentation link I posted said not to do.

Comment: @possum indeed, I was!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting a `key` on a div will cause that div to unmount and remount when the key changes. But it will have no effect on the component surrounding that div (Attribute). If you want to deliberately unmount and remount Attribute, you need to put a key on Attribute. So wherever you're rendering it, do:

```
<Attribute key={`${globalId}-${name}`} globalId={globalId} name={name} value={something} />
```